# Question about Image and Set notation.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

In class we had to show that if $g∘f$ is surjective, then so is $g$ (Where $f: M \to N$ and $g: N \to P$).
We used a proof by contradiction, but I wanted to solve it with a direct proof because it seemed more intuitive to me.

So here is my thought process:
We have given, that $g(f(M)) = P$ and since $ f(M)\subseteq N $ this means that $g("\text{a subset of N}") = P$ (how do you write this?).
So if a subset of the domain maps onto the entire codomain, then obviously the entire domain will also map onto the entire codomain.
So $g(N) = P$  thus $g$ is surjective.

So here are my questions:

1. Does this proof even make sense?
2. How would you formally write this?
3. Is the notation $Im(f) $ the same as $f(M)$ (if $ M $ is the domain)? If so, how would you write this proof using $Im ()$ notation?

Comment: You're trying to prove $g(f(M))=P$ so you can't assume it. I would call that a serious error.

Comment: @CyclotomicField No, that’s given.

Comment: @azif00 you're right.  To prove it directly you should track the preimage of the singletons $\{p\}$ for all $p \in P$. This will basically be the same proof as by contradiction but with more note-keeping.

Answer (score 5):

**1. Does this proof even make sense?**

You wrote: *...So if a subset of the domain maps onto the entire codomain, then obviously the entire domain will also map onto the entire codomain...* I would not call that a proof. The idea is there, but if you want to be convincing, you need to add an argument.

**2. How would you formally write this?**

I would say, let $p \in P$. We have to prove that there exists $n \in N$ such that $g(n)=p$. By hypothesis, $g \circ f$ is surjective. So there exists $m \in M$ such that $g(f(m)) = p$. We get the desired conclusion by taking $n = f(m)$.

**3. About $\operatorname{Im}f$**

$\operatorname{Im}f$ is usually reserved for linear maps.

Comment: @Joe Thanks for improving my English!

Comment: No problem! One other way to formalise @jujoe's argument is to prove that if $A\subseteq B$ then $\phi(A)\subseteq\phi(B)$. Hence, if $f(M)\subseteq N$ then $g(f(M))\subseteq g(N)$. But $g(f(M))=P$ and $g(N)\subseteq P$ (as the codomain of $g$ is $P$), so $g(N)=P$.

Comment: @Joe This is somehow the proof provided by [Milten](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/620957/milten). I have the feeling that it is a bit like using a  sledgehammer to crack a nut... a matter of opinion though.

Comment: I agree that the proof you wrote much is simpler – it's just think that I think the argument using subsets was perhaps closer to how @jujoe was reasoning. There is also a connection between the two methods: what your argument notes is that $g(f(M))=P$, and so for each $p\in P$ there is an $n\in f(M)\subseteq N$ satisfying $g(n)=p$.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I certainly agree that your proof would be the first in my mind as well, but I also think that a subset perspective has merit (and in particular it was a close transcription of OP's proof). If you wanna talk sledgehammers, why not show that $g$ is right-cancelative (and thereby surjective) by $hg=kg \Rightarrow hgf=kgf \Rightarrow h=k$? That works in any category ;)

Comment: @Milten I wasn’t having categories in mind for that question, but I like it!

Answer (score 4):

Correct, $Im(f)=f(m)$, and your proof works as well. If you wish to use $Im$-notation (though it doesn't really change the proof at all), you could write e.g.
$$
P = Im(g\circ f) = g(Im(f)) \subseteq g(N) = Im(g) \subseteq P.
$$
Since $P\subseteq Im(g) \subseteq P$, we conclude $Im(g)=P$. In the above, we used:

- $Im(f) \subseteq cod(f)$ (the codomain of $f$).
- $A\subseteq B \implies f(A)\subseteq f(B)$.
- $A\subseteq B\subseteq A\implies A=B$.

I suppose you also need to convince yourself that $Im(g\circ f) = g(Im(f))$.

Comment: What mathcounterexamples.net says is a good point: It is more common to simply write $f(M)$ rather than $Im(f)$.